# Using avg() and percentage calculation with different where clauses

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to modify the query below to achieve `EXPECTED RESULT` as shown at the bottom of the post. How can modify one of the queries below or both to get what I want?

This only returns total feedback records and the average_rating:

**Version 1)**

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
    ->select('COUNT(f.id) AS total')
    ->addSelect('AVG(f.rating) AS average_rating')
    ->join('f.customers', 'c')
    ->where('c.guid = :guid')
    ->setParameter('guid', $guid)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

**Version 2)**

```
$qb = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT
                COUNT(f.id) AS total,
                AVG(f.ratingSeller) AS average_rating
              FROM
                WhateverBundle:Feedback f
              JOIN
                WhateverBundle:Customer c
              WHERE
                c.guid = :guid'
        )
            ->setParameter('guid', $guid)
            ->getResult();
```

**Current Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 11
            [average_rating] => 4
        )
)
```

**FEEDBACKS TABLE**

```
ID   RATING   DELIVERED   CHECKED   CUSTOMER_ID
1    5        Y           Y         12
2    4        Y           N         12
3    4        Y           N         12
4    5        Y           Y         12
5    2        N           Y         12
```

**CUSTOMERS TABLE**

```
GUID   NAME
12     inanzzz
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
total = 11
average_rating = 4
delivered_percentage = 80% (should take only Y in count)
checked_percentage = 60% (should take only Y in count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CASE` operator:

Version 1:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
    ->select('COUNT(f.id) AS total')
    ->addSelect('AVG(f.rating) AS average_rating')
    ->addSelect('AVG(CASE WHEN f.delivered = "Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS delivered_percentage')
    ->addSelect('AVG(CASE WHEN f.checked = "Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS checked_percentage')
    ->join('f.customers', 'c')
    ->where('c.guid = :guid')
    ->setParameter('guid', $guid)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Version 2:

```
$qb = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT
                COUNT(f.id) AS total,
                AVG(f.ratingSeller) AS average_rating
                AVG(CASE WHEN f.delivered = "Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS delivered_percentage
                AVG(CASE WHEN f.checked = "Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS checked_percentage
              FROM
                WhateverBundle:Feedback f
              JOIN
                WhateverBundle:Customer c
              WHERE
                c.guid = :guid'
        )
            ->setParameter('guid', $guid)
            ->getResult();
```

Funny enough, if you just used the proper `type="boolean"` for your entity mapping, Doctrine would store the `Y` and `N` as tinyint `1` and `0`, enabling you to not have to use the `CASE` operation. You would also be able to use PHP `true` and `false` in your setter and getter functions.

Comment: Excellent. Both work perfectly fine. Yes there are some DB design issues but unfortunately I have to get on with it!

Comment: Cheers! Not hard to fix. Just create a new column, `UPDATE table SET new_column = 1 WHERE old_column = 'Y'` and so on, then delete the old column once everything's mapped. The code however may take a longer time to migrate ;)

Comment: There are plenty of code depend on `Y` and `N` so I'm afraid of breaking all that. Also it is someone else's DB so I only have ready only rights. Anyway, my problem has been solved. Thank again.

Comment: @inanzzz I figured it was the code that was the bigger issue, all the best